# Circuit with dependent & independent voltage sources - Why not matching?

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-measurement, thevenin, voltage-source, norton

I've just solved this exercise by hand and then I have compared the results with PSIM Simulator and there's a difference of e-006 in the Voltage Vo. I just can't understand where's the mistake, I have tried to do it as a normal KCL circuit; then I have also tried to solve it as a Thevenin & Norton... but I just can't see what's the mistake. I suppose it's conceptual.

Furthermore, my results are negative and the Simulator gives them positive... why? I have supposed the current accross the dependent voltage source is negative as it's + to - ...

Please I would appreciate you could find an answer to this question, I'm not asking you to do my homework...

Many thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am not familiar at all with that simulation software, but are you using a voltage controlled voltage supply? And is it measuring the voltage across a current meter? (which should be zero)

Comment: Hello, yes I am using a voltage controlled voltage supply and the voltage depends on the current Ib;; the exercise says that the relation is: 8 * Ib  
I don't understand the second part of the sentence, what do you mean by current meter? and why should it be zero? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOC8LP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we apply a current divider rule for the input network we can find Ib current directly.

$$I_B = \frac{2V}{5\Omega} \cdot \frac{R_1||R_2}{R_1||R_2+R_3} \approx 0.305A $$

Now we can find the voltage (with respect to GND) produce by CCVS (Current Controlled Voltage Source).

$$V = -8\Omega \cdot 0.305A \approx -2.44V $$

And the output voltage can be found using the voltage divider equation:

$$V_{OUT} = V \times \frac{R_5}{R_4+R_5} \approx -1.39V$$

As for the simulation. The original circuit contains CCVS not VCVS as you have used in the simulation.

Also, I do not see a GND symbol on the schematic. 
The PSIM Simulator doesn't require one?

Comment: I think you nailed everything! Including the mistaken use of a VCVS in the simulation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar at all with that simulation software, but by having a voltage controlled voltage supply (VCVS) you should be inputting to it a voltage. In your diagram you have the VCVS G connected across the current meter Ib. Since it is a current meter it will not have a voltage drop across it.

So your VCVS is reading 0 V and outputting some multiple of that, that is, it is just output zero Volts. I suppose those 1e-6 V readings on the output are just numeric error. To check that, measure the voltage being outputted by the VCVS (it should be very close to zero if it is as I said). And also check the voltage drop across Ib (is should also be zero or very close).

To fix that, use a Current Controlled Voltage Supply (CCVS), the simulation circuit will change a bit, since the current has to go through the CCVS and if you want to keep having Ib, Ib should be in series with the measuring input of the CCVS.

Comment: OMG Thanks!!!!!! Now it works perfectly!!!! And one last question; I had supposed the current throught the VCVS would be negative because it gets into the + and leaves from the - ; then when I calculate the Vo I do the following: Vo = Ic * Re : so the Voltage is negative; is it a mistake?? or is it this way??

Comment: Ok, I think the fact is;; Vo = - Ic * Re so - * - = +

Comment: The current in a **CCVS** should go into the + and out through the - terminal. I think Ic will be negative.